# how to pull employees of company from a linkedin API using PHP?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am trying to pull employees of a company using API with PHP.
Please suggest some approaches.

I have tried below search in Linkedin

https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?f_CC=17599&trk=extra_biz_employees_deg_connected

Comment: provide whatever you tried so far!

Answer (score -2):

By using the linkedin apis you can search.

Developer url
https://developer.linkedin.com/

API docs
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs